# How to get tqdm to print to the same line regardless of terminal window size?

Tags: python, bash, tqdm

I'm using tqdm to draw a progress bar and would like tqdm to overwrite the same line in the terminal regardless of the window size. Consider the following code:

```
from tqdm import trange
from time import sleep
t = trange(100, desc='Bar desc', leave=True)
for i in t:
    t.set_description("Bar desc (file %i)" % i)
    t.refresh() # to show immediately the update
    sleep(0.01)
```

When the width of my terminal window is wider than `"Bar desc (file %i)"` , tqdm would print the progress bar as I desire. However, if I reduce the width of my terminal window, tqdm would print to two lines. Every tqdm update would print to a new line. Is there any way round to get tqdm to print to the same two lines even if I resize my terminal?

I'm using bash terminal in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

Either query terminal width and trim your bar accordingly `linewidth=$(($(tput cols) - 1))`
Either disable line-wrap

disable line-wrap:
ncurses `tput rmam`
ANSI: '\x1B[?7l`

enable line-wrap:
ncurses`tput smam`
ANSI: '\x1B[?7h`